# Calculate Cohen's d for pairwise tukey tests in a 1-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, effect-size, tukey-hsd-test, cohens-d

I have the following dilemma:

**Design:** 
1 (Group: Patient vs. Control_1 vs. Control_2) between-factors design arrayed as a 1-way ANOVA

**Analysis:**
Following a main effect of group perform I perform all pairwise comparisons using Tukey tests.

**Question:**
Cohen's d for paired comparisons is the mean difference divided by the pooled standard deviation. This information is not available for Tukey tests. Is there a way to compute Cohen's d or a standardized effect size from these data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily compute Cohen's $d$ using the three means and ANOVA output. The square-root of the MS-error (or MS-residual depending on which program you used) is the pooled within-groups standard deviation. Thus, simply divide each mean difference by this value.